# Accessing Object in PHP

Tags: php, object

I've some strange issues with some php code.

```
if ($user->userType=='admin'){
```

If I use the above command, the php engine just stop interpreting and display the code in plain text on my browser.  On the other hand if I use the below method it works:

```
 if ($user['userType']=='admin'){
```

Again here also:

```
$_SESSION['currentUser']->id
```

If I use the above code it just displays the rest of code as plain text:

```
id); // fail user }else{ $authentication="failed"; $noAuthPresentation="loginForm"; }
```

Why this is happening? It's a big project and I don't want to change every line where there is an occurrence of `->`.

Do I need to change some setting somewhere?  I'm using WAMP server with php 5.5.12.

Any help ? Thanks!

Comment: Please `var_dump($user)` and post the result in your question

Comment: Sounds more like your webserver isn't parsing the PHP at all

Comment: @mark , I don't think so because its loading the home page and I can enter my username and password.

Comment: curiosity: What is the full name of your file (including extension)

Comment: @newBee - are you doing a "view source" in your browser? Or just looking at what is visually rendered?

Comment: Do you have `short open tags` enabled? If not, change your `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: @ Mark Thanks, its at least throwing me some errors!

Thanks Mark, If you put an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up types, user is an array, and not an object.  Something in your php config is doing something strange to your error display it seems.  Right click on the page that has the errors, and view source if possible.

Does login.php contain html and php code by chance?